# How to create a shortcut (but not on desktop!) in Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: 19.04, shortcuts

To run a game designed for Windows, I used Wine to install it and the game runs perfectly.

I also tried to create a shortcut for the game which created a .desktop file.

Now I know that these .desktop files do not work as expected in Ubuntu 19.04 and that to make it work - if it is places on your desktop - you should right-click the shortcut and select "Allow launching".

This works for me. However, I want to place the shortcut to a certain folder instead of my desktop.

But then I don't see any way how to enable "allow launching".

Double-clicking the shortcut only opens my default text editor.

Does anyone has any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal in the folder and run the command `chmod +x name-of-the-program.desktop`.

Alternatively, you can right click on the .desktop file, open properties, and mark the file as executable.

Comment: This does not work (I tested both variants). The .desktop file is marked as executable but it still opens only in my default text editor. In older versions of Ubuntu this used to work but not in Ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 0):

## Legacy way: using shell launcher

Many free software projects are still using a shell script to start the app within multiple platforms.

Shell is portable in most GNU/POSIX environments, also it allows checking the environment before launching the target app.

1. Here a template: `start.sh`

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/sh

   #change directory if needed, some wine games need to be launched from their root directory
   cd gamerootdirectory

   #launch the game
   wine game.exe
   ```
2. Set permissions

   chmod +x start.sh

Now, you can start as same way you expect with desktop files.

**Reference:**

- [Wine User's Guide -  How to run Windows programs from the command line](https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User%27s_Guide#How_to_run_Windows_programs_from_the_command_line)